# Convert Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, dictionary, struct

I'm converting matlab code to python, and I'm having a huge doubt on the following line of code:

```
BD_teste = [BD_teste; grupos.(['g',int2str(l)]).('elementos')(ind_element,:),l];
```

the whole code is this:

```
BD_teste = [];
por_treino = 0;
for l = 1:k
    quant_elementos_t = int64((length(grupos.(['g',int2str(l)]).('elementos')) * por_treino)/100);
    for element_c = 1 : quant_elementos_t
        ind_element = randi([1 length(grupos.(['g',int2str(l)]).('elementos'))]);
        BD_teste = [BD_teste; grupos.(['g',int2str(l)]).('elementos')(ind_element,:),l];
        grupos.(['g',int2str(l)]).('elementos')(ind_element,:) = [];
    end
end
```

This line of code below is a structure, as I am converting to python, I used a list and inside it, a dictionary with its list 'elementos':

```
'g',int2str(l)]).('elementos')
```

So my question is just in the line I quoted above, I was wondering what is happening and how it is occurring, and how I would write in python.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I'm writing an answer, but as general advice, avoid naming a variable `l` it is easy to confuse it with `1`.

Answer (score 1):

`BD_teste = [BD_teste; grupos.(['g',int2str(l)]).('elementos')(ind_element,:),l];`

Is one very weird line. Let's break it down into pieces:

`int2str(l)` returns the number `l` as a char array (will span from `'1'` until k).

`['g',int2str(l)]` returns the char array `g1`, then `g2` and so on along with the value of `l`.

`grupos.(['g',int2str(l)])` will return the value of the field named `g1`, `g2` and so on that belongs to the struct `grupos`.

`grupos.(['g',int2str(l)]).('elementos')` Now assumes that `grupos.(['g',int2str(l)])` is itself a struct, and returns the value of its field named 'elementos'.

`grupos.(['g',int2str(l)]).('elementos')(ind_element,:)` Assuming that `grupos.(['g',int2str(l)])` is a matrix, this line returns a line-vector containing the `ind_element`-th line of said matrix.

`grupos.(['g',int2str(l)]).('elementos')(ind_element,:),l` appends the number one to the vector obtained before.

`[BD_teste; grupos.(['g',int2str(l)]).('elementos')(ind_element,:),l]` appends the line vector `[grupos.(['g',int2str(l)]).('elementos')(ind_element,:),l]` to the matrix `BD_teste`, at its bottom. and creates a new matrix.

Finally:
``` BD_teste = [BD_teste; grupos.(['g',int2str(l)]).('elementos')(ind_element,:),l];``assignes the value of the obtained matrix to the variable ```BD_teste`, overwriting its previous value. Effectively, this just appends the new line, but because of the overwriting step, it is not very effective.

It would be recommendable to append with:
`BD_teste(end+1,:) = [grupos.(['g',int2str(l)]).('elementos')(ind_element,:),l];`

Now, how you will rewrite this in Python is a whole different story, and will depend on how you want to define the variable `grupos` mostly.